# Is a question about decrypting some text actually off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180744/deciphering-an-encryption-algorithm), which is about deciphering some encrypted text encrypted with an unknown algorithm. It's arguably too broad (although I think that it isn't and that the question could lead to interesting and useful answers), but it got closed as off-topic for not being about programming.

My understanding from the help Center is that questions about algorithms are on-topic here. That being said, isn't this particular question on-topic for being about an algorithm?

Comment: But it's not about an algorithm. It's about finding what algorithm it should be about. It's too broad. The OP needs to put in more effort to make it more on topic or maybe move it in a different stack exchange network where it would be more appropriate (maybe it's a puzzle?)

Comment: I've seen users argue that a post must be about programming. I'm not convinced that it must, as the Help Center says "..a specific programming problem, *or a software algorithm*, or.." emphasis mine. I'm not sure about a post where the goal is to identify which algorithm is used is fine or not. As for the effort, I do not think it's possible to put more effort into in without also finding the algorithm, so for me that point is moot, even if we required people to put effort into Questions.

Comment: I can imagine a question about "How can I establish what algorithm was used to encrypt a given message?" being possibly useful to future readers; but that does not appear to be what this is. This seems to be "someone tell me how this specific message was encrypted", which would only useful to people with the same encrypted message.

Comment: @Scratte I'd argue that's not a programming question. I'd further argue it's not a *software* algorithm, either. I don't see how it belongs on SO. At best we have "algorithm" but we can all agree, it's not a programming question in any way. There is Puzzling which might be more appropriate for solving this. Not sure if other stacks deal with identifying encryption.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't understand your argument that it's not a software algorithm. I see encryption algorithms as software algorithms, just as quicksort are software algorithms. Are you expecting the algorithm to be carried out by hand?

Comment: I could see it being closed as too broad, but I'm really not convinced that it is off-topic.

Comment: I find it funny that [even Cryptography.SE doesn't accept this kind of questions](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/18700), but SO wants to... why?

Comment: @AndrewT. You could argue that the question is too broad or too localised, but I'm not convinced that it's off-topic.

Comment: @Scratte We've used encryption a thousand years since we've had computers to run them through. The name Caesar Cypher does come from Gaius Julius himself dating it close to 2100 years ago. Cryptographic analysis *can* be done by a computer and some types of encryption are simply unfeasible to do by humans as they require a lot of calculations. Yet, at its core, cryptography is an applied set of rules that humans can and have done. Outside of some extremely computationally heavy algorithms, the encryption should be solvable by hand. I expect that the encryption used was not computer-only.

Comment: @VLAZ I see. Can you name a software algorithm that would on-topic and included by the phrasing of the Help Center?

Comment: @Scratte first thing that comes to mind is choosing the correct algorithm to shuffle an array with. Or an algorithm to do a random walk through an array without shuffling it. Also possibly a phonetic algorithm if you have a question for how best to do fuzzy matching of strings.

Comment: @VLAZ Wouldn't either of those be very likely to be closed as opinion based?

Comment: @Scratte they *could* be good questions but they also need to specify enough details to be able to identify a suitable algorithm among many.

Comment: I'd just like to say that in this question I'm looking to reverse engineer a specific algorithm that's implemented in minified javascript on another site (see my question for the site url and details). The claim that the question is "about finding what algorithm it should be about" does not make sense to me. My main critique of the closure is that closing this question helps no one, whereas leaving the question open has a slim (certainly quite slim) chance of helping others in the future, not to mention myself in the present. Where on the web can one raise this question if not StackOverflow?

Comment: As I said, I can see arguing for it being too localized or "gimme teh codez," but I really don't see why this is off-topic given that it's about an algorithm.

Comment: @duhaime you should probably make it very clear in the question itself that you got both the encrypted and decrypted texts from https://livebook.manning.com/ and that you are basically trying to crack their obfuscation system allowing you to access for free to a non-free service.

Comment: @Kaiido I intentionally didn't say that because I don't want others to use the algorithm to steal intellectual property (I myself have no interest in doing so--I just want to understand the message on the red piece of paper). I only mention the obfuscated JS to point out that I'm trying to solve a definite programming problem...

Comment: @duhaime and why didn't you just sent an email to manning.com asking them to decipher your so mysterious message?

Comment: "*I really don't see why this is off-topic given that it's about an algorithm*" are ***any*** and ***all*** questions about algorithms on topic? Because my understanding is that the questions should be related to software development. "there exists an algorithm" doesn't necessarily mean it's a software development related question. A finance question can also be an algorithm but we have a separate stack for this. We do have two entire stacks which mostly figuring out the algorithms - Puzzling and Code Golf. I've yet to see an argument why SO should house every algorithm possible.

Comment: Still wondering whether my coffee machine is off-topic. Most problems are debugging or algorithms. It's definitely a commonly used tool in programming. And yes, I'm only half joking.

Comment: @Kaiido Manning.com is not StackOverflow! On the question of gatekeeping algorithms, why _shouldn't_ SO discuss every algorithm possible. What's gained by giving up that intellectual terrain to another stackexchange? Also, on the notion of showing work--as others have said, the work in pursuit of a solution to an encryption scheme has little or no value until the solution itself has been discovered. After wandering through a few thousand lines of possible solutions and coming up empty handed, I thought I would ask those with more experience in cryptanalysis for insight...

Comment: @duhaime so what? If we believe what you said before your goal is to decipher this message you mysteriously got on a post-it. Why don't you ask them if they can do it? Why would StackOverflow be any better place to ask this? If you asked how to program a similar cipher, then that could maybe make sense to post it here, but here you are just trying to decipher a friends joke. How are you even sure there is a cipher algorithm at all? After a quick look at this page they seem to request the clear data from server, so this might actually just be random characters with the correct spaces.

Comment: @Kaiido I am not under the impression that engineers at for-profit companies would have the will or desire to help with this task, especially given the fact that their product security relies on this encryption algorithm, but I'll ask them. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @duhaime I didn't told you to ask for their algorithm, but to ask them to decipher the two words on you post-it.