# Should questions about obfuscated code be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, code

Per [another Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407049/blindly-copy-pasting-code-is-bad-a-gentle-reminder) it came to our attention that there was a user posting potentially malicious code. There's no real rule about that, but, for unrelated reasons of moderation, the account that posted it was deleted.

They later recreated the account and posted another question, which got a bit more decisive response because of the unrelated moderation issue they chose to ignore. The question was a bit less kosher as well (obviously the bad parts have been redacted, and I did not code format so it's all readable in a block)

> I tried decrypt this base64 hash but i can't:

> IO.Compression.DeflateStream ($(New-Object IO.MemoryStream (,$([Convert]::FromBase64String("**A really long Base64 string here**")))), [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)), [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)).ReadToEnd();") else (%WinDir%\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP -NonI -W Hidden -Exec Bypass -Command "Invoke-Expression $(New-Object IO.StreamReader ($(New-Object IO.Compression.DeflateStream ($(New-Object IO.MemoryStream (,$([Convert]::FromBase64String("**A really long Base64 string here**")))), [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)), [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)).ReadToEnd();")

> How i can decrypt it?

Given the prior subject matter, I was disinclined to keep this question (the fact that it's calling a base64 reversal to then execute a PowerShell command is a giant red flag).

But it does raise another issue: Should we allow questions where the user merely wants help figuring out what obfuscated blocks or commands (where hackers have inserted malicious code) do? There's not much value in people just searching for help, and if someone wants to revert it into text and *then* ask what it does, that's a bit less problematic (because the troublesome parts should be considerably more obvious).

Obviously, please mod flag blatantly malicious code and we'll take care of it. But making it off-topic means it can be removed by the broader community as well, via closure and deletion (since red-flags would get confusing without context). The goal here would be for quick removal by the community.

Comment: Weren't these situations usually handled by adding a warning banner to the post? Isn't this enough anymore? The malicious parts can also be removed/replaced if those aren't important to keep the question on-topic.

Comment: Here’s an example question that asks for deobfuscation: [How to decode or decrypt js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67167468/4642212). I’ve voted to close it as too broad. I’ve left this comment: _“This code is not encrypted, it’s just obfuscated. Questions asking us to deobfuscate code are often too broad, as we’d have to either explain every single line (something that the OP should try and do instead by reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)), or too localized, as we’d just dump the deobfuscated code here, which doesn’t help any future reader.”_

Comment: If question is on-topic, then simply removing that encoded part (to make code non-executable) should be enough. I believe it's actually a good thing if SO will also teach about exploits. Sql injection is very well known, so should be the various `FromBase64String`. "How i can decrypt it" is off-topic as too broad.

Comment: I feel these are two separate problems: Is it okay to post code that could obscure whether it is malicious when run? Is it okay to ask questions with no chance of being useful to someone else? I've seen quite some of the former that were genuine questions, and the latter would kill a lot of questions that are perfectly fine today. Is there some (clear, wiggly, or otherwise) line that can be drawn between things that would be off-topic with this suggestion?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321709/how-to-handle-what-does-this-malicious-obfuscated-code-do-questions

Comment: Related https://security.stackexchange.com/q/115461/27973

Comment: @Braiam That's asking how to de-obfuscate. Different ball of wax. I'm not proposing we ban questions about base64 or the like. I'm saying that questions about "How do I use this block of base64" should be off-topic

Comment: @Machavity well you ask "Should we allow questions where the user merely wants help figuring out what obfuscated blocks or commands do?" The first step of the process of figuring out what it does is to de-obfuscate it. Without it, the answer would be "yah, that code is obfuscated, I will not run it in my system".

Comment: To be fair, deobfuscation is crucial part of malware analysis. If someone asks to deobfuscate something and thell him what it does, that means that eighter the person asking caught some kind of script malware, or does a challenge. Asking someone to simply run heavily obfuscated script on their machine is asking for a trouble because they do not know what kind of code is hidden beneath and the only correct response to that is "Sorry, no can do. There is nothing that would make me run this thing on my machine, I don't want to get my computer infected with a malware." No matter the intentions.

Comment: Questions and problems should not be obfuscated more than strictly necessary. Basically when asking about obfuscated code one should motivate very strongly why knowing this is useful programming knowledge. There might be corner cases that are interesting, especially in conjunction with de-obfuscation. Simple explain this code to me questions, regardless of if the code is obfuscated or not, are almost always too broad.

Comment: Is a question that is trying to harm users' computers in breach of the [Stack Exchange Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, the listed reasons do not seem to include malicious intents. Maybe it should include it. You could contact the network and ask them to include it.

Comment: @Trilarion I think it would come under "Illegal Use" in most countries.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You could be right but still it might make an interesting law question. Where does illegal code start? Is all harmful code illegal? Where does harmful start? Is malicious intent necessary? How does one detect harmful code? Would it still be okay to study malicious code in the name of knowledge gathering? ... Should we talk about code safety?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405191/is-a-question-about-decrypting-some-text-actually-off-topic)

Comment: the lua tag sees a fair number of low effort `how do I deobfuscate this code?` questions, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121229/how-do-i-de-obfuscate-a-lua-script) was made and now we simply mark new deobfuscation questions as duplicates of that post.

Comment: Agree with removing such code. Either some hacker profits, or a beginner programmer copies this code and chooses a wrong/unsafe approach to some "problem" using it. It is like SQL-injection but even worse. Better remove it, actually IMHO this kind of construct should not be allowed at all in a common programming platform. Executable code should be on file, local or share.

Comment: @Nifim I like that post, but a suggestion - add links to other related SO questions that explain *how to do* the different suggested steps, with concrete examples. For example, link to a question explaining local variable shadowing and how to get around it.

Comment: **Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange** (yes, we *do* have such site) [might accept them](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malware?tab=Votes)

Comment: From "*making it off-topic means it can be removed by the broader community as well, via closure and deletion*", I take it you are proposing to add a new closure reason.  Equating that with such questions being off topic is confusing, as most of our closure reasons pertain to questions that are *on* topic, but for other reasons are not suitable in their present form.

Comment: @JohnBollinger We don't have any other custom closure reasons to assign to this. I'll be typing a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] up after this, which would explain this rule to future users

Comment: @Machavity, it sounds like you may have misunderstood.  I'm not saying that this particular category already has its own closure reason (though there are other reasons that typically also apply).  I'm saying that it is confusing and probably incorrect to describe the proposal as declaring such questions to be "off topic".

Comment: Who's to judge what is "obfuscated"?  Maybe that's just how I write code! (I like single character variable names and my enter key is broken...)

Comment: Consider too that SO is not for working code.. so if it's working but obfuscated, perhaps it belongs on codereview ;)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Should questions about obfuscated code be off-topic?

**Yes, they should be off topic.**

---

#### Why?

They are generally either too broad or unclear.

Too broad, because posting obfuscated code is basically asking several questions in one. Does OP need help with converting some Base64 string back to code or something else?

Various encodings and conversions have been covered numerous times, so if only that is asked then, obviously such questions would be a duplicate, if there is more, then there are multiple questions.

If there is more than one function used in the code then, again asking multiple questions that were also probably answered before.

And when you sum it all up, it is pretty obvious that it is unclear what is actual problem, beyond OP not knowing where to start.

If by any chance OP had put some effort into de-obfuscation and is stuck on some narrow problem, then it is either no longer de-obfuscation question as such, but asking about some specific functionality (which is on topic, even though possible duplicate), or trying to decipher some data out of context where we can only play guessing games - which would be off topic.

Comment: "...OP had put some effort into de-obfuscation and is stuck on some narrow problem, then it is either no longer de-obfuscation question as such..." So how do I tell the difference between a question about obfuscated code that would be off-topic and a question with some effort that is no longer a de-obfuscation question as such and could still be on-topic? I'm all for it. I just want to get some practical tips for where to draw the line. A more detailed definition of when questions shall still be on-topic might be helpful.

Comment: @Trilarion Usually comes down to "*This is what I tried*". If the OP explains their approach, shows us their attempt and has partially deobfuscated code in their question, it's usually good to go. In the best case, it's a how-to question asking about a particular step of the deobfuscation. Contrast that to code dumps that only say "*I need help decoding this*" or "*What does this code do*", where the OP is asking for the end result only, not for understanding the technique. (Another red flag: they misuse terminology and conflate deobfuscation with decryption).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342164/how-to-properly-deobfusacte-a-perl-script) is a question where I asked to help deobfuscate a Perl script. I show what I tried and where I got stuck in the process of deobfuscating the code myself. I don't think this question narrows down to asking about specific functionality. The accepted answer even goes above and beyond to show how to create such obfuscated code yourself.

Comment: I've posted a pretty well received answer about deobfuscation in javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145796/decode-obfuscated-javascript/6145858#6145858). It's not all black and white

Answer (score 47):

Even if they are on topic, which they are not, and they are not dangerous, which they are, they are too broad and generally not reusable.

It's basically a "explain this bunch of code to me, with a twist". There are many ways to obfuscate code (obfuscation to the obfuscation for each obfuscation technique) and each obfuscation technique is flawed and special in their own way, which makes each question very unique.

Now, there are some on topic questions to be had, for example: "How to detect valid base64 encoded strings?"; "Sandboxing untrusted code", "creating obfuscated code"; etc. but these questions are not them.

Coming back to the first paragraph, about why they are dangerous and off topic, the first is obvious. If you had to ask, then it's obviously untrusted code. The topicness of these questions isn't included in the "practical, specific questions about software development". In practical software development, you don't run untrusted obfuscated code, you protect against it by essentially not allowing its execution.

Security.SE don't want these questions either [because they are basically reverse engineering and only serve the person asking about it](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2193/27973). Basically rehashing the reasons this answer and others put forward.

Comment: This answer is written with a basic tenet: not every question has a place on the SE network.

Comment: What about obfuscated malware analysis? While that may be more on-topic for Security.SE, it would still be on-topic here in my books.

Comment: @IanKemp while analyzing obfuscated malware code might be fun, interesting, and possibly useful for someone... still, what does it have to do with Stack Overflow, and what do we learn from it?

Comment: @IanKemp how would that fit in "practical, specific questions about software development"? Since developers have a very poor track record of correctly assessing and preventing security vulnerabilities, I doubt they have much to say about someone else exploit that isn't easily asked on Security.SE.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes OP needs legitimate help in deobfuscating a piece of code, a piece of code that genuinely does not understand and has no bad intent behind it. Such an hypothetical piece of code (which is not the case on the question's post) would be on-topic, since it is indeed seeking for programming help.

However I think in such cases, there would have been at least an attempt in figuring out what the code does before asking for help, so you would find out a partial solution to the problem at least (for example, "I sent this minified JavaScript code to a deobfuscator and here's the result, I think this part makes a request but I don't know what it does with it..."). In such cases, the "I don't know what this code does, so be careful" should be implicit, although a community edit to explicit that the code might be unsafe to run won't be harmful.

Somebody blasting us with obfuscated code and no attempt to figure out is a low effort question anyway and should be closed, since it's literally the same as getting a (unobfuscated) code snippet and asking "what does all this code do". It needs more focus.

Finally, if the question asked does not relate to obfuscation (so was the case in the first "potential malware" post), obfuscated code does not meet the requirements of a [[Minimal, reproducible example]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since it is unreadable and undebuggable, so unfortunately the community cannot help with that anyway.

Comment: The question in my question was almost certainly malicious since [their previously posted code was doing exceptionally unsafe things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407065/2370483). So, no, that question was not on-topic. You'd be converting an unknown base64 string back into executable form and then running it in a hidden PowerShell (a Windows CLI tool). Hence why I removed the payload first

Comment: Yea, this specific case is just obviously malicious, reposting the same malicious code in a different language? Come on...

Comment: When you say "That question is definitely on-topic", I think you're talking about a hypothetical question of the type you suggested in the previous sentence.  A clear way to phrase that would be "*Such a question* would definitely be on-topic".  Unfortunately your current phrasing of "that question" would normally be referring to the one linked in the meta question you're answering, i.e. the question which the discussion is about.  (I think @Cerbrus and Machavity interpreted it that way when they commented.)  So they're disagreeing with your (unintentional, I think) claim that it's fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Definitely. I should have clarified better that paragraph. I edited the answer and explained a bit better what I meant, thanks for your point.

Answer (score 10):

Try this thought experiment: what would we do if the question was "What does this badly formatted but not deliberately obfuscated code do?" It would almost certainly be closed as "too broad", unless it could be edited to focus on *some specific problem* with reading the code.

The only difference I can see is that de-obfuscating code is occasionally a fun challenge, so people are more tempted to play around and attempt an answer.

Other related questions which would also be off-topic:

- Where can I find a de-obfuscation tool? (Recommendation question)
- How do people obfuscate malware? (Too broad)

There might be specific questions which someone has while *writing* a de-obfuscation tool, or de-obfuscating code by hand; to be on-topic, they would need to be focused and present a Minimal Example with the expected outcome.

Answer (score 9):

When they're dumps of obfuscated code asking for it to be translated, they're no better than a standard gimme-teh-codez question, so yes.

From a liability viewpoint, yes. I'm willing to hazard a guess that 99% of the time that obfuscated code has been obfuscated by someone trying to protect their intellectual property, therefore the poster has broken the law by decompiling it and posting it on Stack Overflow, and that could possibly lead to ramifications of a legal nature against Stack Exchange Inc.

When they're a small, self-contained segment of code from e.g. malware or [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) that someone is trying to understand, then and only then should they be allowed. Base64 strings are an exception; anyone with a bare modicum of reverse-engineering experience can spot these a mile away, and equally should know how to decode them, so the only conceivable use-case for posting a Base64 string that is "obfuscated" would be for malicious purposes, as already discovered.

tl;dr Yes, especially if it's about an "obfuscated" Base64 string. No if, and only if, the question is appropriately narrowly scoped.

Answer (score 9):

If a user posts potentially malicious code **without warning prominently about that,** that constitutes severe abuse of the site and is grounds for mod flagging, immediate question deletion and potentially a ban. And for flagging as spam as well (as users rightfully did to the original linked question) so that it's hidden faster (a post is automatically hidden if 3 users flag it as spam IIRC).

In other cases, it's still closeable for other reasons: too broad/unclear (as explained in other answers), "no MCVE" (since either the obfuscation, or the payload (malicious or not), or the part that executes the payload, are an extraneous detail) -- except very few very specific cases (as also explained in other answers).

Answer (score 5):

If a post is used only as a trick to try and see if anyone inadvertently executes the included potentially malicious code on their system, then it is off topic.

If the post is asking a genuine, unique question about malware de-obfuscation, or more generally about how obfuscation works, it seems natural that it should be allowed in scope rather than a special hole be cut to forbid such questions.

If the post can be interpreted either way (which is perhaps often the case), it should be edited to preserve the apparent question structure but remove the potentially dangerous payload.  For example, anyone can replace a really long Base64 string by **"A really long Base64 string here"**.

Could the removal of the detail harm the question by removing all but the outermost layer of obfuscation? (For all we know, there might be multiple.)  Probably not, if the thing that looked like a Base64 string really was a Base64 string:

1. Independent questions should be asked independently.
2. In the rare case that the first step of deobfuscation could not be determined without knowing the payload, the original form of the question is accessible through edit history.  The extra steps to navigate the history serve as a confirmation that the user is well aware of the difference between  Base64 string and a placeholder and less likely to eventually shoot themselves into the foot by doing something silly with the original, perhaps dangerous form in which the question was asked.

Comment: While I agree that this doesn't need "a special hole", I think such questions generally fail _existing_ tests for quality and topic.

Comment: @IMSoP - True.  And most of those that remain are duplicates.  There are existing tests for all that.

Comment: This highlights my concern with "cutting a special hole" to forbid these question; our means of curating the site shouldn't come at the cost of losing otherwise good questions. If these sorts of questions are *already* generally too broad or outright harmful, then we, by definition, don't need a special case or reason; just close them under the normal reasoning and move on.

Answer (score 2):

I originally typed this up late at night so I didn't have time to make my own proposal, and some confusion has snuck in that this is an attempt to ban creating or reversing encoded text (i.e. base64, just because it is the most ubiquitous). That was never my goal and I tried to convey that in the question. I guess I should be more explicit. The good thing here is that listening to the community feedback here helped me refine my ideas some.

The goal here is to make it clear that **trying to execute or otherwise use obfuscated code** is off-topic. That was the problem with the question I deleted that prompted me to make this post in the first place. The code clearly took some block of code behind a base64 block of text and then washed it through something that evaluates that code (i.e. [Javascript's eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)) which, as that question explains, is a bad idea

> Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks

So, to be clear, what I'm proposing is

1. Questions about making or reversing encoding are **on-topic** (i.e. [How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string))
2. Questions about how to use code-within-code functions that can arbitrarily execute code (i.e. [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) are **on-topic**
3. Questions about using the two together in a purely academic way (i.e. you make pseudo-code that contains no actual obfuscated code) are **on-topic**
4. Questions where you *provide encoded data that engages in arbitrary execution* are **OFF-TOPIC**

The goal here would be that we'll have a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry explaining this in detail so the community can close and/or delete them in a way that anyone asking these questions can have a point of reference.

Comment: As long as it's a "practical, answerable problem unique to software development" it's probably fair game. Other things still apply, if it's unclear, it's unclear. If it's too broad, it's too broad. If it's opinion based (eg. "best method to execute code-within-code") it should be closed as that. **It's not a litmus test.**

Answer (score -12):

Base64 is not an obfuscation, but only an encoding (without mappings) - which makes it a bad example. From a technical point of view, code obfuscation is not much different from transpiling.

I think that code obfuscation questions are fine, to some degree also code de-obfuscation questions, but as soon one may suspect illegal activity (theft of IP), one should better step up; which should already be possible - without having to declare illegal activity as "off-topic".

And one should rather forget about the notion, that there always is a good intent given.
Been there, done that - while the mere problem usually is to treat crooks with politeness
(due to this policy-based wrongful notion); any child knows the internet is full of scammers.

The difference is the intent of the asker - and the most meaningful would be to consider that - instead of declaring it off-topic altogether. I mean, there's people who want to make sure to obfuscate as much as possible of their own source code - and there are people who want to obtain other people's source code. That's a huge difference, while here the problem is, that some of the crooks may make up some more or less plausible-sounding story, in order to justify their otherwise deletion-worthy question (or account). It's interesting from a psychological point of view, but when being gullible, one may be tricked into supporting crime.

I remember one case on AskUbuntu, where I had been dearly attacked, only because I've referenced the LUKS brute-force decryption tool from the official Ubuntu repository. With such tools is is just alike with firearms ...and one has little responsibility for the intent of the one who uses them - which may or may not be legitimate (no matter the story being told).

In reality, this user only flipped out, because I've proven to them what a joke that password-based security is... and I'd wonder what the intent behind declaring it all as "off-topic" may actually be?

The only logical consequence of declaring de-obfuscation as "off-topic", would be to also declare decoding (as in the given example) and decryption (as in my example) as "off-topic"... because it is all the same, with minor variations. And as stated, when suspecting illegal activity, it's not much effort to raise a red flag. When declaring a wide topic as "off-topic", it may not be clear, where exactly to start and where to stop... especially based upon one single example, which isn't even about de-obfuscation. Please get your terminology straight, to begin with.

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. "Obfuscation" just means (to quote [Wiktionary's defintion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obfuscation)) "concealing the meaning of a communication by making it more confusing and harder to interpret". Certainly, base64 could be used for purposes _other than_ obfuscation, but code that has been base64 encoded is certainly "more confusing and harder to interpret" than code which hasn't, and in the example given was encoded that way specifically for that purpose.